# Rails 3 DRY partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, scope, partial

I have a Rails 3 application with a view that is irritating me. The view is essentially four tabs. Each tab shows a filtered list of records like this:

**Tab One**

```
<% @faults.each do |fault| %>
    <%= fault.name %>
<% end %>
```

**Tab Two**

```
<% @faults_pending.each do |fault| %>
    <%= fault.name %>
<% end %>
```

**Tab Three**

```
<% @faults_closed.each do |fault| %>
    <%= fault.name %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously there is a lot more code that I have missed out. To tidy the view up significantly I considered making a partial for each tab, however, each of those partials would be identical except for the `<% @faults.each do |fault| %>` line.

Is there a way of having one partial and somehow when rendering the partial set the scope (or method, I can never remember what it's called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for render's :locals option.

Tab one

```
<%= render :partial => "faults", :locals => { :faults => @faults } %>
```

Tab two

```
<%= render :partial => "faults", :locals => { :faults => @faults_pending } %>
```

Tab three

```
<%= render :partial => "faults", :locals => { :faults => @faults_closed } %>
```

Partial

```
<% faults.each do |fault| %>
  <%= fault.name %>
<% end %>
```